# Code.ensure_loaded? in .iex.exs

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I have an elixir console configuration stored in `.iex.exs`:

```
if Code.ensure_loaded?(MyApp.Repo) do
  alias MyApp.Repo
end
```

I want to have an ability to run both `iex` and `iex -S mix`. I'll have exception if I remove condition on `iex`.

But this conditions doesn't work well! Even on `iex -S mix` I have `(module Repo is not available)` error if I'm trying to invoke `Repo.get(...)`. So, my questions are:

1. Why `Code.ensure_loaded?` doesn't work here?
2. How can I fix that?

Comment: (1) is because the `alias` is lexical and is only effective inside that `if`. Not sure about (2).

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of scoping. Inside a block, you have this alias defined:

```
if Code.ensure_loaded?(MyApp.Repo) do
  alias MyApp.Repo
  Repo.get(...) #⇒ available
end
```

To define an `alias` IEx-wide, you should call it outside of any block:

```
alias MyApp.Repo
```

You do not need a conditional `if Code.ensure_loaded?(MyApp.Repo)` when `IEx` is executed with `iex -S mix`, all the dependencies will be loaded for you automagically. For pure `iex` this might be done in more cumbersome way:

```
defmodule FileExt do
  def ls_all(dir, acc \\ []) do
    case File.ls(dir) do
      {:ok, list} -> list |> Enum.reduce(acc, fn f, acc ->
          fullname = dir <> "/" <> f
          if fullname |> File.dir?, do: ls_all(fullname, acc), else: acc ++ [fullname]
        end)
      {:error, e} ->
        IO.puts "Unable to list. Reason: #{e}"
        acc
    end
  end

  def require_lib do
    try do
      "lib" |> FileExt.ls_all |> Kernel.ParallelRequire.files
    rescue
      e in UndefinedFunctionError -> Code.ensure_loaded?(MyApp.Repo)
    end
  end
end

try do
  MyApp.Repo.get
rescue
  e in UndefinedFunctionError -> FileExt.require_lib
end

alias MyApp.Repo
```

The above would load all files from the `"lib"` directory.

Though I would shut the perfectionism up here and go with `iex -S mix` always, without check:

```
Code.ensure_loaded?(MyApp.Repo)
alias MyApp.Repo
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the requirement "I want to have an ability to run both `iex` and `iex -S mix`".

Comment: @Dogbert indeed, I updated an answer to explicitly load `"lib"` dir.

Comment: @mudasobwa looks good, but I got a lot of warnings, like `warning: redefining module MyApp.Module`. How can I solve it?

Comment: You got these warnings while using the `FileExt.ls_all |> Kernel.ParallelRequire.files` with `iex -S mix`, right? Obviously, this is a case because `iex -S mix` takes care about loading everything from `"lib"` itself. Check whether `Repo` is defined in advance to distinguish the behaviour between pure `iex` and `iex -S mix`: `try do MyApp.Repo.get rescue e in UndefinedFunctionError -> LOAD_ALL_THIS_STUFF end`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I still see these warnings; just copy-pasted your code and replaced `MyApp` with my application name

Comment: `MyApp.Repo.get/0` must exist with zero arity for this code to work. I obviously can’t guess the _real_ function you would call to check whether the code was already loaded or not. I thought you’ve got the point, sorry. Inside `try` call _the definitely existing function_ to check whether the code was loaded.