# How can I make running iex with `-S mix` always for specific project?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

This question is caused by Alexey Matushkin answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503311/code-ensure-loaded-in-iex-exs).

How can I make `iex` always run with `-S mix` option, and only for specific project? Maybe there is something I can place in `.iex.exs` which I overlooked...

**UPDATED**

- I want to run `iex` only from project directory
- I have Ubuntu installed

Comment: Do you want to call it from anywhere? Only from the project directory? Please clarify the desired input and expected result in different situations. BTW, you’ve made several typos in my name.

Comment: @mudasobwa sorry for typos. I haven't seen your name spelling in english :( Can't get `Please clarify the desired input and expected result in different situations`

Comment: @mudasobwa updated

Comment: An alias (or if you also want it to work with non Mix projects, a function which checks for `mix.exs` and conditionally starts `iex` or `iex -S mix`) in your shell might be the simplest way but I'm not sure if that would be acceptable for you.

Comment: On my workstation I use `alias mex="iex -S mix"` and this is the most robust solution in my opinion. Also, automation suggested by @Dogbert would definitely work, but a) it is out of your control and b) `mex` is not so hard to type :)

Answer (score 0):

- use an alias e.g. `alias iexsm="iex -S mix"`
- if you run the command once, hitting the up arrow on your keyboard should bring it back again, so the need for having an alias should be minimum
- if the project folder is fairly constant, you can have something along the lines of `cd ~/dir/to/project && iex -S mix`, execute it once. Next time you want to run it, press ctrl + r (in a linux/mac terminal) and just type the name of the project